# Is it possible to display in house map in mapbox android

Tags: android, mapbox, in-house-distribution

Is it possible to display in house map using MapBox in Android?

For example : I am in one mall and I want to know that what are the directions of particular shop in one mall or I want to know that how many shops of cloths are there in one mall using MapBox?

All your answers and suggestions are valuable and appreciable for me.

Looking forward to your reply.

I am using MapBox Android SDK : https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/

Comment: The short answer to your question is Yes! It is possible - you will have to do some work first though.

Comment: yes it is possible, check here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml#introduction

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I am using MapBox Android SDK see I have updated my question and I want to do the same using MapBox SDK

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, you are trying to create an indoor map using the Mapbox Android SDK correct? If that is the case, you can follow [this guide](https://www.mapbox.com/help/georeferencing-imagery/) to tracing the indoor map you have and create a tile set. You then can use it within your Android app by following this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/custom-raster-style/).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried as you have suggested but it doen't works for me on that scenario which I want as In door mapping. Can you please explain in detail how can I get this using that. All it's showing is the normal map. Please advice

Comment: Sure, I'll need a little more detail from you first such as what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know how to build a custom  map in QGIS, how to upload a map? Is that map is private to my app? Can I get the current location of user in custom Indoor Map?. Can I get Indoor navigation from store A to Store B with navigation marker? Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Very sort answer is yes it is possible,

For inhouse may you have to create custom geographical area image for particular mall and its floor

Here is some reference for your idea  [video for concept](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATfdi-oYWzw&noredirect=1) here is one concept of showing indoor image either by web service or you can also 
 [Create your own drawable image for indoor map](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#shape-drawable)

Comment: Thanks Ajay for your answer but I want to do it using **MAPBOX** Android SDK. Please provide me link or example for that. Please find the SDK link from my updated question